# Proving polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Prove that when you graph a quadratic with one root and coefficient $2$ contain a point $(a,b)$ such that the trinomial $b^2 +wx uq$ also has one.

I am still unsure of whether the question is saying at least 1 root In an attempt to solve the question, I've tried completing the square, trying to rewrite the polynomial in vertex form and letting the discriminant be 0. So far, I can't seem to find a relationship.

Comment: Do you know how to give the general form of `a quadratic trinomial with one (repeated) root and leading coefficient 1`?

Comment: This: $(x-h)^2 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

A monic quadratic with a repeated root takes the form $p(x) = (x+a)^2$.

Notice at $x=-2a$, we have the point $(x,p(x)) = \left(-2a, a^2\right)$.

Now, consider $q(x) = x^2 - 2ax + a^2$. We see $q(x) = (x-a)^2$, so $q$ also has exactly one root.